# Get href using css selector with Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I want to get the `href` value:

```html
<span class="title">
  <a href="https://www.example.com"></a>
</span>
```

I tried this:

```
Link = Link1.css('span[class=title] a::text').extract()[0]
```

But I just get the text inside the `<a>`.  How can I get the link inside the `href`?

Comment: Could you give more details on what you're using & the code you're trying to parse? Might wanna try `a::@href` or `a::href` to select the attribute.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
Link = Link1.css('span[class=title] a::attr(href)').extract()[0]
```

Since you're matching a `span` "class" attribute also, you can even write

```
Link = Link1.css('span.title a::attr(href)').extract()[0]
```

Please note that `::text` pseudo element and `::attr(attributename)` functional pseudo element are **NOT** standard CSS3 selectors. They're extensions to CSS selectors in Scrapy 0.20.

---

Edit (2017-07-20): starting from Scrapy 1.0, you can use `.extract_first()` instead of `.extract()[0]`

```
Link = Link1.css('span[class=title] a::attr(href)').extract_first()
Link = Link1.css('span.title a::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

Comment: The "extract()[0]" looks bad, is it possible to `extract` a single value not a list?

Comment: There's this proposal: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/568 (quite a lot of debate).
With this PR: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/624 . I personally would like to see `.get()` and `.getall()`

Comment: Where can I see all Scrapy's CSS extensions? Can't find it in the docs.

Comment: Scrapy's extensions are documented in Parsel docs (the selectors library): https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#extensions-to-css-selectors

Comment: Replace `extract()[0]` with `extract_first()`

Comment: you can simply use `Link = Link1.css('span.title a::attr(href)').get()`

Comment: Yep, that's the new recommended syntax

Answer (score 8):

```
Link = Link1.css('span.title a::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

[you can get more infomation from this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
Link = Link1.css('span.title a::attr(href)').extract()
```

`Link` will have the value : https://www.example.com