# How can I get the data from a css selector using scrapy?

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm a noob to web and scrapy.  Sorry for the simpleness of this question.

I've got this: `item['title'] = response.css('.pt-title a ::title').extract()`

And I want to get the title from this:

```
<a href="http://www.heresyodomain.com/" title="Here's the title!">Here's the title!</a>
```

I was doing this `item['title'] = response.css('.pt-title a::text').extract()` but I realized that I was just getting the text not in the tag.

I've tried a few iterations of what I have above, that's just the last one I left off on.  A little guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query selects the text of the `a` tag because of `a::text`. If you need the `title`'s text try the following:

```
item['title'] = response.css('.pt-title a::attr(title)').extract()
```

Eventually you get back a list, so you should take care of that too with `item['title'] = response.css('.pt-title a::attr(title)').extract()[0]` -- after proper validation of the result of course.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this question:
[python scrapy get href using css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181628/python-scrapy-get-href-using-css-selector) I got an answer.

I used this: `item['title'] = response.css('.pt-title a::attr(title)').extract()`