# How can I get an element inside a class with scrapy using response.css

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get value="3474636382675" from:

`<input class="lst" value="3474636382675" title="Zoeken" autocomplete="off" id="sbhost" maxlength="2048" name="q" type="text"`>

I've tried

```
response.css(".lst >value").extract()
```

This one works but i'm getting everything back and i just need the value.

```
response.css(".lst").extract()
```

Answer (score 5):

With CSS you select the attribute you want like this:

```
response.css(".lst::attr(value)").extract()
```

You can read more about the selectors in Scrapy’s [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I use beautiful soup to parse html. Here's an example that grabs stock prices from yahoo finance.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getPrice(tag):
    source = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+tag
    filehandle = urllib.request.urlopen(source)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(filehandle.read(), "html.parser")
    priceSpan = soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "Fz(36px)" })
    for k in priceSpan:
        return(k.getText())

def getDayChange(tag):
    source = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+tag
    filehandle = urllib.request.urlopen(source)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(filehandle.read(), "html.parser")
    priceSpan = soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "Fw(500)" })
    for k in priceSpan:
        return(k.getText())
```

https://gist.github.com/Krewn/0e624d35c396df63262dd42d74f2beb6

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about css. But [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181628/python-scrapy-get-href-using-css-selector) from another SO answer. Alternatively try xpath:

```
response.xpath('//input[@class="lst"]/@value').extract()
```

or if you need only one value:

```
response.xpath('//input[@class="lst"]/@value').extract_first()
```

Comment: It works with xpath, thanks. But how would you do it with response.css ?

Comment: Looks legit to me.

Comment: @Rousblack Seems someone else already answered your question. Also you can follow the link and see if the answer works for you.