# How to get the Href from the : <a class=''...' href= ''...''> using Scrapy with css selectors

Tags: scrapy

<a class="mod-gallery-article__media mod-gallery-article__media--img has-lightbox"

href="/content/dam/aldi/netherlands/products/nieuw/7089_MIENESTJES_02.png/_jcr_content/renditions/opt.1250w.png.res/1531142854839/opt.1250w.png"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get href using css selector with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181628/get-href-using-css-selector-with-scrapy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: response.css('a::attr(href)').get()
Out[1]: '/content/dam/aldi/netherlands/products/nieuw/7089_MIENESTJES_02.png/_jcr_content/renditions/opt.1250w.png.res/1531142854839/opt.1250w.png'
```

Comment: @DanGeorgeBostan No problem, please accept the answer.